# Twitter bootstrap Typeahead not triggering on entering in textbox

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-typeahead

I am trying to implement bootstrap Typeahead in my code but for some reason, when I enter any text in my textbox, nothing happens (I am trying to get data using ajax call and expected code to run on every text entered)

**Code**

`<input id="searchQuery" type="text" placeholder="Search" class="search-query" />`

**Javascript**

```
    $('#searchQuery').typeahead({    
        minLength: 3,          
        source: function (query, process) {
            $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: xxx,
            datatype: 'json',
            cache: false,
            data: { searchText: xxx },
            success: function (aData) {
                process(aData);
            }
        });
    }});
```

I expected my code to call this javascript everytime I enter a character in my textbox, but nothing happens.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way...

```
$("#searchQuery").typeahead({
  source: function(query, process) {
    return $.ajax({
      url: "XXX",
      type: "GET",
       data: { searchText: xxx },
      success: function(result) {
        return process(result);  // this returns an array checked with console
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: your solution seems to work but can you explain what exactly made it work? I didnt change anything except taking out minLength parameter.

Comment: just see my post clearly i mentioned return .....u miss that one...noe u got it ah..